# Spark UDF Overloading

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement that the Spark UDF has to be overloaded, I know that UDF overloading is not supported in Spark. So to overcome this limitation of spark I tried to create an UDF that accepts Any type and inside the UDF it finds the actual datatype and call the respective methods for computation and returns value accordingly. When doing so I got an error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:213)
    at com.experian.spark_jobs.Test$.main(Test.scala:9)
    at com.experian.spark_jobs.Test.main(Test.scala)
```

Below is the sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    spark.udf.register("testudf", testudf _)
    spark.sql("create temporary view testView as select testudf(1, 2) as a").show()
    spark.sql("select testudf(a, 5) from testView").show()

  }

  def testudf(a: Any, b: Any) = {
    if (a.isInstanceOf[Integer] && b.isInstanceOf[Integer]) {
      add(a.asInstanceOf[Integer], b.asInstanceOf[Integer])
    } else if (a.isInstanceOf[java.math.BigDecimal] && b.isInstanceOf[java.math.BigDecimal]) {
      add(a.asInstanceOf[java.math.BigDecimal], b.asInstanceOf[java.math.BigDecimal])
    }
  }

  def add(decimal: java.math.BigDecimal, decimal1: java.math.BigDecimal): java.math.BigDecimal = {
    decimal.add(decimal1)
  }

  def add(integer: Integer, integer1: Integer): Integer = {
    integer + integer1
  }
}
```

Does it possible to make the above requirement possible? If not please suggest me a better approach.

**Note:** Spark Version - 2.4.0

Comment: could you add a snippet where you register the udf and launch it?

Comment: @Kamrus, I had updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem working with Dataframe(untyped) is that it is very painful doing something like some kind of polymorphism at compile time. Ideally, having the column types will allow to build your udfs with the specific "add function" implementation, like if you were working with Monoids. But Spark Dataframe API is very far away from this world. Working with Datasets or with [Frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless) help a lot.

In your example, to examine the type at runtime you will need AnyRef instead of Any. That should work.

Comment: The problem I am facing is with the return type(Spark not accepting multiple return types for UDFs) and not with the parameters, and the type Any is working fine with the parameters, please guide me on that part, Thanks.